# Can't add comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, ios-app

When viewing a comment via a notification, I can't reply to it. Same when I go to a question from the recent activity. The comment button is missing entirely.

Using the beta app on an iPhone 5s.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There seems to have been a glitch of some sort (was seeing the sites in read-only mode) a few minutes ago. Can you still reproduce this? (perhaps after recycling the app?)

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be happening any more. It was only when using those two methods, so didn't appear to be site-wide. But looks good now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a temporary issue.

Several sites went read-only as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276096/what-was-the-downtime-for).  The logic for `can_comment` returns `false` when the site is read-only which is why the button disappeared.  (Add answer remained because of laxer client-side logic.)

Unfortunately, the API doesn't currently expose that the site is read-only so there was no way for the app to convey that.